# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG and POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH issues, fixing one impacting the other

Tags: ssh, dns

Just purchased cellular dongle to replace my internet with cellular solution. After a while I started to get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` and site stopped working for me. Checking a bit the solution was to change "Obtain DNS server address automatically" to use google DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

After a short while I started to get a new problem with SSH connecting to familiar hosts `SSH Error: WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH`. Saying server's host key does not match putty cached in the registry.

If I connect to a different wifi network I manage to connect via ssh to those servers without the error.

Was the DNS solution is wrong? Is there a better way to fix that chicken-n-egg thing?

**Update:** so it seems with the new wifi sometimes I manage to connect without the ssh error and sometimes not.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get rid of that ISP...

Comment: it is the biggest ISP for mobile sim over here

Comment: This is indicative of a MITM (Man In The Middle) attack, it could be malicious, but I would more suspect a misconfiguration of equipment somewhere, likely the ISP. Something is changing the SSH key enroute.

Comment: It is an issue, what can I do?